# How can I run a class method inside of a public void from a different class?

Tags: class, void, public

So I have a method like so (Method1):

```
public class Levels extends JFrame{
    public void levelClass() {
        if(menu.playerClass.equals("Warrior")) {
            // I NEED COMMAND HERE
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to know how to run this class method (that is in a different class):

```
public class Classes {
    public void listClasses() {

        class Warrior { // THIS ONE
            int health=100;
            int evasionChance=20; // Percentage
            int maxAttackDamage=30;
            int minAttackDamage=25;
            int numHealthPotions=2;
        }
    }
}
```

from the first code aka Method1.

> **Edit**

***DON'T***

Change all:

```
public class Classes {
    public void listClasses() {

        class Warrior {
            int health=100;
            int evasionChance=20; // Percentage
            int maxAttackDamage=30;
            int minAttackDamage=25;
            int numHealthPotions=2;
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
public class Classes {
    public void Warrior {
        int health=100;
        int evasionChance=20; // Percentage
        int maxAttackDamage=30;
        int minAttackDamage=25;
        int numHealthPotions=2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a method on a class, you need to instantiate the class.

```
public class Levels extends JFrame{
    public void levelClass() {
        if(menu.playerClass.equals("Warrior")) {
            // instantiate the Classes class
            Classes classes = new Classes();
            // call the warrior method
            classes.warrior();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: levelClass is already being started elsewhere but I want to run class Warrior from the     // I NEED COMMAND HERE code

Comment: Specifically the class Warrior one

Comment: Notice the          // THIS ONE

Comment: You can edit your original post instead of creating an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this xD

Comment: No problem, we all start at the beginning! :)